# OID (directory service) Installation and configuration on Windows 2003 R2

Tags: windows, oracle, internet, directory, service

I need your help in installing and configuring Oracle Internet Directory service on Windows 2003 R2 server machine, I was wondering if anyone can provide any useful tutorial links on the same. I did google, but i was still unable to accomplish the task. Iam totally new to the scenario of OID and directory services other than MS-AD.

Thank You
 Jacob

Answer (score 1):

Found the below link which can help for Oracle Internet Directory (OID) on linux -: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/id-mgmt/ods11g-use-cases-084303.html#Option1

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Internet Directory (OID) is part of the Oracle Identity Management suite.  So you can start by looking [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/id-mgmt/overview/index-082035.html).   This page includes the installation and configuration guide links which should help you out.